# JAVA two way communication between classes

Tags: java, swing, class, parameter-passing, this

I want to be able to create an instance of my Client class in my GUI and then pass GUI.this as a parameter for the Client constructor but I'm not sure exactly how to do that. I know I'm missing something obvious! I want to be able to call methods on the other from either class. Obviously I have commented code out because I don't know how or what I am supposed to do to achieve this two way communication without merging the classes! I want to be able to do stuff like send a command through the Client from the GUI class when the "Up" button is clicked on the GUI etc. Thanks for the help in advance.

Client class:

```
    public class Client{
    //static playerGUI GUI;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //GUI = new playerGUI();
        //GUI.getFrame().setVisible(true);
        //Client cli = new Client("localhost",4444);
    }

    public Client(playerGUI GUI){   
        try{
        final Socket sock = new Socket("localhost",4444);
        final DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());

        final PrintStream out = new PrintStream(sock.getOutputStream());
        DataInputStream inputLine = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(System.in));

        final Thread serverResponse = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                System.out.println("DUNGEON OF DOOM HAS STARTED");
                if(sock != null){
                    if(in != null){
                        try{
                            String response;
                            while((response = in.readLine()) != null){
                                //GUI.processgrid(response);
                                //send to GUI to process output!
                                System.out.println(response);
                            }
                        }catch(UnknownHostException uhe){
                            System.err.println("Unknown host1: " + uhe);
                        }catch(IOException ioe){
                            System.err.println("IOException1: " + ioe);
                        }catch(NullPointerException npe){
                            System.err.println("Null Pointer1: " + npe);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        serverResponse.start();

        if(sock != null){
            if(out != null){
                try{
                    while(true){
                        //inputbuttons!
                        String sending = inputLine.readLine();
                        out.println(sending);
                        if(sending.equals("QUIT")) break;
                    }
                }catch(UnknownHostException uhe2){
                    System.err.println("Unknown host2: " + uhe2);
                }catch(IOException ioe2){
                    System.err.println("IOException2: " + ioe2);
                }catch(NullPointerException npe2){
                    System.err.println("Null Pointer2: " + npe2);
                }
            }
        }

        out.close();
        in.close();
        sock.close();
    }catch(UnknownHostException uhe3){
        System.err.println("Unknown host3: " + uhe3);
    }catch(IOException ioe3){
        System.err.println("IOException3: " + ioe3);
    }catch(NullPointerException npe3){
        System.err.println("Null Pointer3: " + npe3);
    }   
    }
}
```

GUI Class:

```
public class playerGUI {
    private JFrame Frame = new JFrame();
    private JPanel displayPanel;
    private JTextPane hostTextPane;
    private JTextPane portTextPane;
    private playerGUI GUI;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        playerGUI GUI = new playerGUI();
        GUI.Frame.setVisible(true);
        Client newclient = new Client(this.playerGUI);
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public playerGUI() {
        Frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        Frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        Frame.setBounds(100, 100, 500, 630);
        Frame.setUndecorated(false); // REMOVES MENU BAR
        Frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // ############################################################################################################################################################################

        final JPanel humanGameWindow = new JPanel();
        humanGameWindow.setLayout(null);
        humanGameWindow.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        humanGameWindow.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 600);
        humanGameWindow.setVisible(false);

        JLabel gameTitle = new JLabel("DUNGEON OF DOOM!!");
        gameTitle.setForeground(new Color(100, 149, 237));
        gameTitle.setFont(new Font("Moire", Font.BOLD, 28));
        gameTitle.setBounds(92, 5, 380, 50);

        JButton up = new JButton("Up");
        up.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // ######################
            }
        });
        up.setBackground(new Color(100, 149, 237));
        up.setBounds(274, 514, 100, 40);

        JButton down = new JButton("Down");
        down.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // ######################
            }
        });
        down.setBackground(new Color(100, 149, 237));
        down.setBounds(274, 555, 100, 40);

        JButton left = new JButton("Left");
        left.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // ######################
            }
        });
        left.setBackground(new Color(100, 149, 237));
        left.setBounds(173, 535, 100, 40);

        JButton right = new JButton("Right");
        right.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // ######################
            }
        });
        right.setBackground(new Color(100, 149, 237));
        right.setBounds(375, 535, 100, 40);

        JButton pickup = new JButton("Pickup");
        pickup.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // ######################
            }
        });
        pickup.setBackground(new Color(100, 149, 237));
        pickup.setBounds(40, 555, 100, 40);

        JButton Exit = new JButton("Exit");
        Exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        Exit.setBackground(new Color(100, 149, 237));
        Exit.setBounds(427, 17, 70, 40);

        displayPanel = new JPanel();
        displayPanel.setBounds(48, 89, 400, 400);
        displayPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 5));
        displayPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int) (400), (int) (400)));
        for (int i = 1; i < 26; i++) {
            displayPanel.add(new JLabel("Label " + i));
        }

        humanGameWindow.add(gameTitle);
        humanGameWindow.add(up);
        humanGameWindow.add(down);
        humanGameWindow.add(left);
        humanGameWindow.add(right);
        humanGameWindow.add(pickup);
        humanGameWindow.add(Exit);
        humanGameWindow.add(displayPanel);

        final JPanel mainMenu = new JPanel();
        mainMenu.setLayout(null);
        mainMenu.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        mainMenu.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 600);
        mainMenu.setVisible(true);

        JLabel mainMenuTitle = new JLabel("DUNGEON OF DOOM!!");
        mainMenuTitle.setForeground(new Color(100, 149, 237));
        mainMenuTitle.setFont(new Font("Moire", Font.BOLD, 28));
        mainMenuTitle.setBounds(50, 13, 380, 50);

        hostTextPane = new JTextPane();
        hostTextPane.setToolTipText("Enter the host name");
        hostTextPane.setBackground(new Color(192, 192, 192));
        hostTextPane.setBounds(50, 100, 234, 30);
        hostTextPane.setFont(new Font("Moire", Font.BOLD, 19));

        portTextPane = new JTextPane();
        portTextPane.setToolTipText("Enter the port");
        portTextPane.setBackground(new Color(192, 192, 192));
        portTextPane.setBounds(50, 175, 234, 30);
        portTextPane.setFont(new Font("Moire", Font.BOLD, 19));

        JButton playGameHuman = new JButton("Play Game Human");
        playGameHuman.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                mainMenu.setVisible(false);
                humanGameWindow.setVisible(true);
                                //not sure if i need to be creating the Client here?
                /*
                 * if (!(hostTextPane.getText().equals("")) &&
                 * !(portTextPane.getText().equals(""))) { try { Client cli =
                 * new Client(hostTextPane.getText(), Integer
                 * .parseInt(portTextPane.getText())); } catch (Exception e1) {
                 * System.out.println("Error."); } } else {
                 * JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                 * "Do not leave hostname or port no. blank."); }
                 */
            }
        });
        playGameHuman.setBackground(new Color(100, 149, 237));
        playGameHuman.setBounds(50, 345, 150, 55);

        mainMenu.add(mainMenuTitle);
        mainMenu.add(mainMenuQuit);
        mainMenu.add(playGameHuman);
        mainMenu.add(hostTextPane);
        mainMenu.add(portTextPane);

        getFrame().getContentPane().add(humanGameWindow);
        getFrame().getContentPane().add(mainMenu);
        getFrame().setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: Please use Java naming conventions: classes should start with a uppercase letter, and variables with a lowercase.

Comment: I realise everyone wants me to follow this naming convention, but conversely I think you need to realise that I do what I want. No, but in all seriousness if I do my best in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        playerGUI GUI = new playerGUI();
        GUI.Frame.setVisible(true);
        Client newclient = new Client(GUI);
    }
```

Comment: Which class is this intended for?

Comment: I just changed your code a bit in the PlayerGUI class

Answer (score 0):

`main` is a static method, which means it is run in a static context (ie, not "as" any instantiated object). This means you can't access `this` in `main` because there is no `this` to access. You need to access playerGUI with just `playerGUI` or `playerGUI.playerGUI` in your `Client.main` method. Also, you need to set the field `playerGUI.playerGUI` to static.

Comment: Also, consider using standard java naming convention, ie classes are CapitalizedCamelCase. The way you have it, it is hard to tell the difference between `playerGUI` (class) and `playerGUI` (field)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
Client newclient = new Client(this.playerGUI);
```

you need this:

```
Client newclient = new Client(GUI);
```

Notice that as `main` is static there is no `this` defined.

Also consider changing the names of your class and variables to follow Java naming conventions:

- `playerGUI` should be `PlayerGUI`
- `GUI` should be `gui` or whatever you feel like but starting with lowercase

Also do you notice that you are not using that field called `GUI`? You are only using the variable `GUI`. So it may be adding up to the confusion.

Comment: Yeah but how do I actually send the data from one class to the thread, say through a button press.